# sending binary a type variable (struct) over serial port

Tags: serialization, vb6, serial-port

Is it possible at VB6 to send whole contents of a type (struct) over serial port ?
The following example doesnt works.

```
Private Type CommFrameStruct 
   node As String
   Inputs As Byte
   Outputs As Byte
End Type
```

at form load...

```
Dim msg As CommFrameStruct
msg.node = "TEST"
msg.Inputs = 5
msg.Outputs = 2

MSComm1.PortOpen = True
MSComm1.Output = msg
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the InputMode property of the MSComm control to comInputModeBinary

You can then convert your UDT to an raay of bytes and send that

Two quick example projects :

One project to send the UDT :

```
' form with :
'  1 command button: name=Command1
'  1 MSComm control: name=MSComm1

Option Explicit

Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)

Private Type CommFrameStruct
   node As String * 10
   Inputs As Byte
   Outputs As Byte
End Type

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Dim msg As CommFrameStruct
  Dim bytArr() As Byte
  msg.node = "TEST"
  msg.Inputs = 5
  msg.Outputs = 2
  ReDim bytArr(Len(msg) - 1) As Byte
  CopyMemory bytArr(0), msg, Len(msg)
  MSComm1.Output = bytArr
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
  With MSComm1
    .InputMode = comInputModeBinary
    .Settings = "115200,N,8,1"
    .PortOpen = True
  End With 'MSCOmm1
End Sub
```

And one project to receive the UDT :

```
'1 form with :
'  1 Textbox control: name=Text1  multiline=true
'  1 MSComm control : name=MSComm1
Option Explicit

Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)

Private Type CommFrameStruct
  node As String * 10
  Inputs As Byte
  Outputs As Byte
End Type

Private mudtMsg As CommFrameStruct

Private Sub Form_Load()
  With MSComm1
    .InputMode = comInputModeBinary
    .RThreshold = Len(mudtMsg)
    .Settings = "115200,N,8,1"
    .PortOpen = True
  End With 'MSComm1
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Resize()
  Text1.Move 0, 0, ScaleWidth, ScaleHeight
End Sub

Private Sub MSComm1_OnComm()
  Dim lngIndex As Long
  Dim bytArr() As Byte
  With MSComm1
    Select Case .CommEvent
      Case comEvReceive
        bytArr = .Input
        For lngIndex = 0 To UBound(bytArr)
          ShowText "Byte " & CStr(lngIndex) & " : " & CStr(bytArr(lngIndex))
        Next lngIndex
        CopyMemory mudtMsg, bytArr(0), Len(mudtMsg)
        ShowText "Node: " & mudtMsg.node
        ShowText "Inputs: " & mudtMsg.Inputs
        ShowText "Outputs: " & mudtMsg.Outputs
    End Select
  End With 'MSComm1
End Sub

Private Sub ShowText(strText As String)
  Text1.SelText = vbCrLf & strText
End Sub
```

There are probably more elegant ways (especially for converting the UDT to byte-array and back), but this seems to work :)